# Mixing PHP and HTML in variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a Wordpress plugin that adds a button below all posts. The button is a "Like" button that pass some parameters through the URL to a new site.

The parameters are Wordpress permalink, title, and blog name.

Can't make it work.

```
function add_bloglovin($content) {

   $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');
   $link = the_permalink();
   $title = the_title();

   $bloglovin ="<br><a href=\"http://www.bloglovin.com/like/?b=$blog_title&p=$link&t=$title\" onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'bloglovin_like', 'width=480,height=320, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=0, status=0'); return false;\"><img src=\"http://www.bloglovin.com/widget/bilder/like.gif\"></a>";
   return $content .$bloglovin;
}
add_filter('the_content', add_bloglovin);
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? what's failing?

Comment: it adds the first $blog_title into the $bloglovin variable.. but not $link and $title .. is it php or wordpress that's cousing the problem?

Comment: you probably need to urlencode() the code before you put in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the_permalink() is a display function.  Use get_permalink() to return a string that you can use.  To make the_title return just the title with no wrapped HTML you need to use the_title('','',false);

```
function add_bloglovin($content) {
    $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = the_title('','',false);
    $bloglovin ="<br><a href=\"http://www.bloglovin.com/like/?b=$blog_title&p=$link&t=$title\" onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'bloglovin_like', 'width=480,height=320, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=0, status=0'); return false;\"><img src=\"http://www.bloglovin.com/widget/bilder/like.gif\"></a>";
    return $content .$bloglovin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Wordpress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

**Function Reference/the permalink**

> Displays the URL for the permalink to
>   the post currently being processed in
>   The Loop. This tag must be within The
>   Loop, and is generally used to display
>   the permalink for each post, when the
>   posts are being displayed. Since this
>   template tag is limited to displaying
>   the permalink for the post that is
>   being processed, you cannot use it to
>   display the permalink to an arbitrary
>   post on your weblog.

You can't use $link = the_permalink(); in isolation unless it's in [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: not true though.. shanethehat code above works fine! i just had to use get_ in front of the variables i got from wordpress.. so it's inside the loop.. $content is inside of the loop, I added code behind it.

Comment: Hey! I said the Codex says can't use the_permalink() function [OR get_permalink() either in fact] UNLESS it's in a loop. Your original post does not show if it's referenced in a loop or not, so I was telling you to check that just in case. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try a basic sanity check by `var_dump()`ing the `$link` and `$title` variables. Do they actually contain a string?